# Checking value of argc

Tags: c, argc

I have problem with the number of argc that passed to program
so, when i check the argc it's not equal to 2 !!
need help, how can i solve that problem ?

C code snippet :

```
if (2 != argc) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it should be equal 2? How do you run it?

Comment: You should really try to improve your question...

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what is being asked here -- the code snipped seems to accomplish exactly what you want.

Comment: I fixed the title to somewhat relate to your question, but you should really try to improve this more.

Comment: This has nothing to do with sockets at all.

Comment: Also, this problem has **nothing to do with sockets.** You could have tagged this question with `perl` or `automatic reference counting` as well...

Comment: The code given seems to be correct, your issue is most likely elsewhere.

Comment: i have to get at least 2 argc to start dealing with port number

Comment: The code provided is correct.  Your problem is somewhere else.  رمز هو الصحيح. مشكلتك هو في مكان آخر.

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget that the program name itself counts as an arg.

`myProgram -flag variable` is an `argc` of `3`